# How to update different fields based on conditions in single call

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

```
public class Job
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public bool IsPending { get; set; }

    public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
}
```

I have two lists of Ids named `List<Guid> A` and `List<Guid>B`.

For `List A`, I want to set `Update.Set("IsPending", True)` and

for `List B`, I want to set `Update.Set("IsComplete", True)`.

I am able to achieve this by two db calls:

```
this.UpdateManyAsync(Builders<Job>.Filter.In(f => f.Id, A), Builders<Job>.Update.Set(x => x.IsPending, true), cancellationToken: cancellationToken)
```

and the second call as

```
this.UpdateManyAsync(Builders<Job>.Filter.In(f => f.Id, B), Builders<Job>.Update.Set(x => x.IsComplete, true), cancellationToken: cancellationToken)
```

Is it possible in a single DB call?

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TOQl1CFEAAD) what you want?

Comment: @ray yes. but i want in MongoDB.Driver c# query

Comment: I think it is hard to implement with Fluent API, you can consider passing the UpdateDefinition with BsonDocument.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible to implement Fluent Api as the MongoDB .NET driver doesn't support the `Set` method with the second parameter as `Expression`. These are the available methods:

```cs
public UpdateDefinition<TDocument> Set<TField>(FieldDefinition<TDocument, TField> field, TField value)
```

```cs
public UpdateDefinition<TDocument> Set<TField>(Expression<Func<TDocument, TField>> field, TField value)
```

To achieve your requirement, you can pass the update query with aggregation pipeline as `BsonDocument[]` with `Builders<Job>.Update.Pipeline()`.

Note that in the MongoDB document, I store the Guid value as a string type, thus it is required to specify the mapping rule for the Guid serialization and cast the Guid to string in order to make the query works.

```cs
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers;

BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Job>(
    map =>
    {
        map.AutoMap();
        map.MapProperty(x => x.Id).SetSerializer(new GuidSerializer(BsonType.String));
    });

UpdateDefinition<Job> update = Builders<Job>.Update.Pipeline(new BsonDocument[]
{
    new BsonDocument("$set",
        new BsonDocument
        {
            {
                "IsPending",
                new BsonDocument("$cond",
                    new BsonDocument
                    {
                       {
                            "if",
                            new BsonDocument(
                                "$in", 
                                new BsonArray
                                {
                                    "$_id",
                                    BsonArray.Create(A.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList())
                                }
                            )
                        },
                        { "then", true },
                        { "else", "$IsPending" }
                    }
                )
            },
            {
                "IsComplete",
                new BsonDocument("$cond",
                    new BsonDocument
                    {
                       {
                            "if",
                            new BsonDocument(
                                "$in", 
                                new BsonArray
                                {
                                    "$_id",
                                    BsonArray.Create(B.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList())
                                }
                            )
                        },
                        { "then", true },
                        { "else", "$IsComplete" }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    )
});
```

> Demo

[image]